# How can I get a list of users and computers they have used from these tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a weird anomaly happening in my program. I have a piece of software that ties users and computers together, then sends user information to a server in the cloud.

The software that ties users and computers together stores the user / computer information in a local DB in these table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Computers](
[ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Computers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User_Computer](
[ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[ID_User] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[ID_Computer] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_User_Computer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User_Computer]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_User_Computer_Computers] FOREIGN KEY([ID_Computer])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Computers] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User_Computer] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_User_Computer_Computers]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User_Computer]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_User_Computer_Users] FOREIGN KEY([ID_User])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User_Computer] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_User_Computer_Users]
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
[ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[Name] [nchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

After the user / computer is stored in the local DB, the user guid is used to transmit data to the server in the cloud.  What is interesting is the server in the cloud has 200 user guids and my local DB only has 177 when I run this script.

```
SELECT
Users.ID AS ID_User, 
Users.Name AS UserName, 
User_Computer.ID AS Association, 
User_Computer.ID_Computer, 
Computers.Name AS ComputerName
FROM Users INNER JOIN User_Computer ON Users.ID = User_Computer.ID_User     INNER JOIN
Computers ON User_Computer.ID_Computer = Computers.ID
```

My question : Is there anyway my script is not collecting all of the user information correctly?

NOTE: I am putting data in both the user and computer tables correctly.  What I am interested in is if the script is using the correct join.  should it be inner, outer or something entirely different ?

NOTE: (again) When I run this on my local computer I get this:

```
5FCD88C8-04B5-494C-88C8-85BCD08CBBB5    Fred                                            B945300D-7CED-42FC-8A79-4FDBB54F6B69    29CAD425-42A0-478F-8966-1448144EB90E    Comp1
E357B7E7-7328-4D2D-9A3E-20FC388C5781    Joe                                             7BB73859-8CE3-4383-BAFF-504DBF719524    182627C5-F91D-4C88-9AE3-A527E55A5A41    Comp2
F8C2DB79-85AC-408A-A858-B0C0FA6862F7    Moe                                                 23267708-2A5E-497A-B91A-937D28983832    B518614E-A243-47D1-B642-D24B434D7683    Comp3
237947BC-C26D-44D0-9AF7-F231D98F1BF3    Curly                                               F89411A9-787B-4A2A-AA1E-B56455B781E8    29CAD425-42A0-478F-8966-1448144EB90E    Comp4
3C8DCE89-6764-4D57-B0AD-2CF988EADB35    Steve                                               1D464AB1-DA70-4ACC-8D00-ED7F47D35413    9446327A-30BA-492F-9A28-3AB132C31988    Comp5
F8C2DB79-85AC-408A-A858-B0C0FA6862F7    Moe                                                 A32FD03E-B777-4D74-8702-F58D71B53E8B    82A39A46-269B-43D5-B7A6-B14A9D5FBBD4    Comp6
```

So... what I really want to know with the stored proc is a listing of all of the users and what computers they are associated with.

What I want to do is combine these two stored procedures into one:

```
SELECT
    Users.ID AS ID_User, 
    Users.Name AS UserName, 
    User_Computer.ID AS Association, 
    User_Computer.ID_Computer
FROM Users INNER JOIN User_Computer ON Users.ID = User_Computer.ID_User 

SELECT Computers.ID, 
   Computers.Name, 
   User_Computer.ID AS Association, 
   User_Computer.ID_User
FROM   Computers INNER JOIN User_Computer ON Computers.ID = User_Computer.ID_Computer
```

Comment: so you are stating that with that exact same sql statment, NOT a simple SELECT COUNT(*) users at one location and that statement locally, you get 200 results in cloud and 177 locally?  That would mean that your databses are not in synch.  If you are in fact using different statements the JOIN could be dropping off records because a combination of computer to user may not exist for every user which you can test/look at using FULL OUTER JOIN

Comment: Your `INNER JOIN` filters to only users that have computers (ie. exist in each of the tables).  If that count is 200 locally, but 177 on the web, then you could have datatype or truncation issues on transferring the last 23.  But more likely than not, 23 users don't have computers and are filtered out by the join.

Comment: Users will always have a computer associated with them and they also may have more than one...

Comment: @Matt - no what I am saying is the cloud results are obtained using a different stored proc than mine... but the number of users should be the same in both locations... because the program that records the user/computer relationship sends the user guid to the cloud

Comment: @AaronD - you have the numbers backwards, it's 200 in the cloud and 177 locally.  but the cloud can only get the guid from the local DB.  So the local DB has 200, but the stored proc is only returning 177.

Comment: If it is a different stored proc than yours post the relevant code from the cloud procedure then we will be able to compare them because if the sql statements are not the same there can be dozens of reasons why your count would be different.  And if you are curious about which join you should use try them all and find the results you want we cannot possibly know what you should use without knowing your data and your intent.

Comment: Have you verified that the row counts match up between the individual tables?

Comment: Start with a basic `SELECT UserID FROM Users`, then add each join and see if the count changes.

Comment: @AaronD - I cannot get to the DB that the original data comes from... it is on a client machine in a different company

Comment: what I want is a list of users and the computers they have used.

Comment: Hmm well on a simple viewing of your tables and the query, I see no reason why your query would not return exactly that.  As for why the counts are different, we on SO really have no way of knowing without being able to troubleshoot from your end.  Since web has more than local, my first thought would be that old data is cleaned from local and not from the web.  So there should really be 177 on the web, but 23 have not been deleted that no longer exist locally.  But again, that is just a starting point.

Comment: @AaronD - that's what I thought as well... but the "missing" ones from the local DB have data that has been added to them to the cloud AFTER they were added to the cloud.  So the local DB created them, and then the local DB sent data using the user GUID to the cloud later on, but the local DB no longer has them returned in the above stored proc ????  ( ps... the local DB never deletes data )  Which makes me think the stored proc is wrong

Comment: Assuming the join predicates are correct, and they really should be by *looking* at the structure, then the only possible way that the query is wrong is if data is missing from one of the joined tables.  `INNER JOIN` will only display records that exist in both tables.  `LEFT JOIN` will keep all data from the original table, even if there is not a match between the joined table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT u.ID AS ID_User, u.Name AS UserName, 
       uc.ID AS Association, uc.ID_Computer, 
       c.Name AS ComputerName
FROM Users u INNER JOIN
     User_Computer uc
     ON u.ID = uc.ID_User INNER JOIN
     Computers c
     ON uc.ID_Computer = c.ID;
```

Returns one row for every user/computer pair in the data.  If your foreign keys are set up, then this should be the same number of rows as in `User_Computer`.

If some users do not have computers (which a comment states is not possible), then you can use  a `LEFT JOIN` to get *all* users and information about associated computers, if any

```
SELECT u.ID AS ID_User, u.Name AS UserName, 
       uc.ID AS Association, uc.ID_Computer, 
       c.Name AS ComputerName
FROM Users u LEFT JOIN
     User_Computer uc
     ON u.ID = uc.ID_User LEFT JOIN
     Computers c
     ON uc.ID_Computer = c.ID;
```

If your query and the other stored procedure are returning different results then either (1) they are running on different tables (perhaps in different databases) or (2) they are implementing different logic.  Without seeing the other logic, it isn't possible to say what the difference is.